# How do I get the table to display only data with a specific substring in it

Tags: sql

I have to show all products that contain the word "Transducer" in them. I CANNOT use LIKE. I have tried using contain and I get a invalid relational operator error. I've tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. I'm using SQL Developer 4.

Code:

```
SELECT product_name, name
FROM a_product p JOIN a_item i
ON p.product_id=i.product_id
JOIN a_sales_order so ON i.order_id=so.order_id
JOIN a_customer c ON so.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Output:

```
PRODUCT_NAME                   NAME                                        
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------
Aft Transducer                 Just Electronics                              
75 Gauge Wire Line             Timelines                                     
Aft Transducer                 Vollyrite                                     
Nts Transducer                 Every Mountain                                
Snyder Lock Switch             Shape Up                                      
Nts Transducer                 Shape Up                                      
Sft Transducer 55              Vollyrite                                     
75 Gauge Wire Line             Shape Up
```

I also as I mentioned tried to use contains, but it gave me the error. This is what I used:

```
WHERE contains(product_name, 'Transducer')
```

Which I added after the join statements.

The desired output would look like this:

```
PRODUCT_NAME                   NAME                                        
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------
Aft Transducer                 Just Electronics                                              
Aft Transducer                 Vollyrite                                     
Nts Transducer                 Every Mountain                                              
Nts Transducer                 Shape Up                                      
Sft Transducer 55              Vollyrite
```

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use LIKE? Any reason I could imagine would be the same or even worse with the alternatives.

Comment: The teacher said we can't. Because if I could it would have been the first thing I did.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: How do I tell? Im still very new to SQL and all I know is im using SQL Developer 4.

Comment: Is Oracle 10g a database type?

Comment: The "teacher" isn't doing a good job at teaching. Using LIKE is the most natural approach. There are other ways, but good code means "readability" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use LIKE because it's a problem for school, an alternative is REGEXP_LIKE:

```
SELECT product_name, name
  FROM a_product p
  JOIN a_item i
    ON p.product_id = i.product_id
  JOIN a_sales_order so
    ON i.order_id = so.order_id
  JOIN a_customer c
    ON so.customer_id = c.customer_id
 where regexp_like(product_name, 'Transducer')
```

Comment: In order to use contains you'd have to create an oracle text index first, see some info here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#g1020588

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

```
 "SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `name` REGEXP *Transducer*
```

Or something like that?